# signature mismatch on observable.bindcallback

Tags: typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I'm currently doing an ionic2 application.
So at a time I need to call facebook Accountkit.login(type, params, callbackFn);
I'd like to make a Observable return; [Following the docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) I do:

```
let obs = Observable.bindCallback(AccountKit.login); // it's ok !
  return obs(type, params)                           // <---- error: signature mismatch
      .map(response => this.loginCallback(response));
```

seems to be a typescript issue, I couldn't find any practical solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the `bindCallback`

```
let obs = Observable.bindCallback<YourTypeOfType, YourTypeOfParams, YourTypeOfResponse>(AccountKit.login);
```

You of course have to replace `YourTypeOfType` with the corresponding type (i'm guessing `string`?) and the same with `TypeOfParams` and `TypeOfResponse`

As a quick tryout you could also use `any` for each:

```
let obs = Observable.bindCallback<any, any, any>(AccountKit.login);
```

Comment: I never would have found this ! Maybe I should learn about specific topic on typescript ?

Comment: Often a "type mismatch" or "signature mismatch" is related to some default-typing being provided by a framework - in this case the default-typing of `bindCallback` assumes 1 parameter of your provided method (`login`) - in this case you will have to explicity state the correct type-signature.

With Typescript 2.1 however this should become easier and developers should not need to worry about this as much any more, as such types could be detected automatically by the compiler, however it may take some time until this gets implemented into all the frameworks.